# Markov chain Monte Carlo, Mixing Time

Tags: time-series, markov-process, gibbs

How do you estimate the mixing time for a markov chain?

I read somewhere one can use the sum of the auto-correlation coefficients or the sum of the auto-covariance coefficients, but I cannot seem to find a source that gives more details on this.